# LLVM: How to traverse Module metadata to find a value?

Tags: llvm

I have this metadata tree in my LLVM module:

```
!meta.test = !{!0}    
!0 = !{"str1", "str2", !1}
!1 = !{!2, !3, null}
!2 = !{"str3", i8 5}
```

I want to be able to get the value: i8 5.

I am trying it using M->getNamedMetadata("meta.test"), but I'm unable to traverse the metadata tree using the LLVM API to reach that value.

How should I do this?

Cheers.

Comment: what error you are getting and what llvm api version?

Comment: @lazyCoder: I am not getting any error, I just don't find the appropriate API calls to get that data. What would be the appropriate calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For LLVM 3.6 onwards

`getNamedMetadata` returns `NamedMetadata`, you can use `getOperand(unsigned)` to get `MDNode` and can cast to your appropriate type as per your use.

so `M->getNamedMetadata("meta.test")->getOperand(0)` will get you `metadataNode !0 MDNode`.

you can use `cast< ValueAsMetadata >(MDNode)->getvalue()` to get `Value i8 5`

or you can use `cast< MDString >(MDNode)->getString()` to get `Value str1`.

so in short you can traverse metadata `MDNodes` using `getOperand()` call and cast it to your use as per hierarchy.  see [this](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Metadata.html) for more info.

Comment: thanks, that's it! I couldn't find how to traverse Metadata in the official documentation. Those casts is what I needed.